# What happened related flow and powerapps when changed site url?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, power-automate, powerapps-forms, modern

I'm using SharePoint Online modern experience.
I was thinking of moving everything from the verification site to the production site, but since it is difficult and take many time, I want to change the site URL.
What happens to the associated PowerApps, PowerAutomate and SharePoint custom form with PowerApp if I change the site URL?
Does it require a lot of manual work after changing the URL?

I would appreciate any idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, once you change the URL of the site, the related Flows and Power Apps will stop working.

This is because they still retain the original site URL, but the site l no longer exists.

Therefore, you need to manually connect them to the new URL. This is indeed a lot of manual work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about SharePoint custom PowerApps form(SharePointIntegration)?

Comment: Hi Hyonta. According to my test, it will not affect the normal operation of the custom PowerApps form.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. You mean I have to do nothing for SharePoint custom PowerApps form? It will automatically apply the new site URL to it?

Comment: Hi Hyonta. In my test, I didn't need to do anything, the custom PowerApps forms still worked. Of course, if some custom PowerApps forms stop working, then I suggest you need to re-establish the connection.